# "config_get_device_record: failed to read blah-blah.plist" when iPhone is connected to Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, iphone

I connect my iPhone to an Ubuntu computer just to charge it (without the need for any other actions), and my logs are spammed every second with

```
Apr 04 20:04:26 <user> usbmuxd[4610]: [20:04:26.345][1] config_get_device_record: failed to read '/var/lib/lockdown/<some long id>.plist': No such file or directory
```

I don't need to transfer any data, is there a way to stop this message from appearing whenever I charge my device?